# Objective-C: Singleton Pattern Usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c

suppose I got a singleton class MySingleton as coded below.

Now is a singleton class just like any other class. I can have instance variables that are nonatomic and retain?

I can have: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* instanceVar in the .h file

and @synthesize instanceVar in the .m file?

```
static MySingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;

+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedMySingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMySingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Want to note that ARC will break existing Singleton implementations. They recommend using ARC to implement similar from now on.

Comment: You should use `dispatch_once` instead `@synchronized`, [it's 20x faster](http://bjhomer.blogspot.com/2011/09/synchronized-vs-dispatchonce.html).

Comment: If you're going to be multithreading then you want your singleton properties to be atomic to avoid race conditions (as well as wrapping the critical sections of your code with @synchronized directives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the instance of a singleton class behaves the same as a standard class, there is just one instance.

The pattern you have is overly complicated, there is no need for `+(id)alloc`
Here is a simplier pattern:

```
@implementation MySingleton
static MySingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;

+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            _sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedMySingleton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You bet.  To the rest of your application, your singleton looks and works just like any other class.  The only difference is that when your application tries to create a new singleton it always receives back the same object.  But the singleton can have instance methods and instance variables just like any other class.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the annotations you mentioned because I'm a C++ developer, but a singleton can certainly have instance data. That's one of its values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have instance variables, a singleton is simply a regular class, where there is only one instance at any given time.